# mod_rewrite in htaccess redirecting instead of rewriting and not working 100%

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm in a siutation where I need static pages to take over for much of a wordpress site I'm working with.  I have created a `/static` directory in order to hold the static pages, but I also need to keep the exiting blog visible.  I have the following code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog index\.php [L]
RewriteRule ^20* index\.php [L]
RewriteRule ^$ static [L]
```

Going to `mydomain.com/blog` or `mydomain.com/2014/01/blog-post` both work, but if I try to go to `mydomain.com` the URL is being **redirected** to `mydomain.com/static` which is not what I am trying to accomplish.

Additionally, trying to visit any other page such as `mydomain.com/about.php` throws a 404 error which makes me think my rewrite is entirely wrong.  Essentially I want all requests except for the blog page and blog posts to be rewritten to the files in `/static`

Answer (score 1):

You need a trailing at the end of the directory or else mod_dir and `DirectorySlash` will redirect the browser to the URL with the trailing slash. So you're 3rd rule needs to be:

```
RewriteRule ^$ static/ [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, although that didn't entirely fix the issue.  The index.php from within `/static` that I want to load is loading without the redirect, but other pages (such as about.php) are still throwing a 404 as are assets such as css files and images within the `/static` directory

Comment: @Bizarro181 that's because your regex pattern is `^$` which will *only* match `/` and nothing else.

Comment: I've tried modifying that last rule, but everything seems to be giving me an Internal Server Error (I'm pretty much just trying everything I can think of/see online...htaccess generally makes little sense to me)

Comment: @Bizarro181 the problem that you're having has nothing to do with redirecting to `/static/`, you have to figure out what you want to do, and I'm suspecting that your rules are looping indefinitely which wil cause a 500 server error.

Comment: Hey Jon - Okay, I think I'm closer, but not quite there.  My last rule now involves the following 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /static/$1 [L]`
Although I'm not entirely sure _why_ it's working, but its now working 100% for subpages `mydoamin/about.php` but not for the index page `mydomain.com/index.php` or `mydomain.com`